# How to get exact featureinfo in wms layer Geoserver when polygon is small?

Tags: openlayers, shapefile, geoserver

I got neighbor polygon feature info instated of clicked polygon feature info.
In My Code:

```
getfeaturenfo :function(e) {

            coordinates=e;
            var params = {
                        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                        projection: "EPSG:4326",
                        EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                        BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                        SERVICE: "WMS",
                        INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                        QUERY_LAYERS: selectlayer(map.zoom),
                        FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                        Layers: selectlayer(map.zoom),
                        WIDTH: map.size.w,
                        HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                        X:parseInt(e.xy.x),
                        Y:parseInt(e.xy.y),
                        CQL_FILTER:selectfilter(),
                        srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};


                    // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                    if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                        params.version = "1.3.0";
                        params.i = e.xy.x;
                        params.j = e.xy.y;
                    } else {
                        params.version = "1.1.1";
                       params.y = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                        params.x = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                    }
                    OpenLayers.loadURL("http://myserver/tomcat/geoserver/india/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
```

In Layer Preview I got same issue,So is that problem with layer or with code?

N.B: If Polygon is big then it shows perfect featureinfo but when it's small then this issue occurs.

How Can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional parameter [buffer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#buffer):

```js
var params = {
    buffer: 0,
    ...
}
```